# Enviar email cangularjs 2 + Php

Tags: php, angular

Estou tentando enviar email porém não estou conseguindo.

Minha classe php

```
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage("br", "libs/"); // ajusto a lingua a ser utilizadda
$mail->SMTP_PORT = "587"; // ajusto a porta de smt a ser utilizada. Neste caso, a 587 que o GMail utiliza
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // ajusto o tipo de comunicação a ser utilizada, no caso, a TLS do GMail

$mail->IsSMTP(); // ajusto o email para utilizar protocolo SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  // especifico o endereço do servidor smtp do GMail
//$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // ativo a autenticação SMTP, no caso do GMail, é necessário
$mail->Username = "Meu email";  // Usuário SMTP do GMail
$mail->Password = "Minha Senha"; // Senha do usuário SMTP do GMail

$mail->From = "Meu email"; // Email de quem envia o email
$mail->FromName = "Teste"; // Nome de quem envia o email
$mail->AddAddress("Email que estou enviado"); // Endereço e nome de quem vai receber o email, o nome é opcional

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // quebra linha sempre que uma linha atingir 50 caracteres
$mail->IsHTML(true);  // ajusto envio do email no formato HTML

$mail->Subject = "Assunto"; // Aqui colocar o assunto do email
$mail->Body     = "Este é o corpo da mensagem <b>, por isso, para exemplicar que este cabeçalho tem suporte html, este está em negrito!</b>"; 
$mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem para usuários que possuem a opção de ver o html do email desativada em seu cliente de email";      

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
     echo "Mensagem não pode ser enviada. <p>";
     echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }

     echo "Mensagem enviada";
```

mudei meu código php para seguinte:

```
// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->Username = "meu email"; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = "minha senha"; // Senha do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
$mail->Port='587';

$mail->From       = "meu email";
$mail->FromName   = "meu nome";

// Define os destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress("email destinatario", 'Douglas');

// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
$mail->Subject  = "teste"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "";
$mail->AltBody = "Mensagem enviada";

// Define os anexos (opcional)
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");  // Insere um anexo


$enviado = $mail->Send();


$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

if ($enviado) {
  echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
   echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.<br /><br />";
   echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> <br />" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

e ativei seguinte opção: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Comment: nesse caso deve-se ver a mensagem de erro ao tentar enviar o email na linha `echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;`.

Comment: tenho seguinte erro: NÃo foi possível enviar o e-mail.Informações do erro:You must provide at least one recipient email address.